# To the Questioners: Did you receive the kind of answers you expected?

Tags: discussion

This is kind of a poll question, but I think its important.

Are the answers that were written in your question what you expected to get from a lifehackers community?

Comment: I think this is important some answers were really weak. IDK about the downvote 1+

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish with this question? You should know how askers feel based on their responses - accepting an answer and comments

Comment: @ZachSaucier I see that there are many questions who do not have answers accepted and at least for my question I know I did not receive the answers I was expecting. So now I want to figure out if this impression is for me alone (thats fine, than this is just not my community) or if there are others getting the same impression (then I could figure out what kind of answers were expected.)

Answer (score 4):

Well, I self answered this:

[How do I remove dust from fabric lampshades?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-do-i-remove-dust-from-fabric-lampshades)

And I think it was a great lifehack. But both (q and a) got downvoted.

And my answer here:

[How can I clean a vase that I can't reach inside?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/73/how-can-i-clean-a-vase-that-i-cant-reach-inside/86#86)

Promotes a tool designed specifically for the purpose, and it got upvoted. Either I or the other voters are somewhat confused.

But most of the questions I asked got a number of answers, at least one of which is a legit answer I'm liable to try on each of them. I *only* accept answers that I seriously take as good advice.

Comment: Well, the complaint that it isn't sporting to answer your own question is a pretty good indication of what users care about here.

Comment: And what is it that you object to, @J.Musser?

Comment: @KevinJohnsrude See Matt's comment, above. :)

Comment: @J.Musser, I think you may be taking things a little too personally. We all have an interest in seeing this site succeed and I'm doing my part.

Comment: @KevinJohnsrude huh? What does that have to do with it?

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I wasn't sure what types of answers I expected to get and *I feel like that was a problem when asking my questions*. A lot of the answers made me think more closely about how I would need to word future questions to avoid people posting the common sense answers (for example, on the barbecue ribs question I got a lot of "eat differently" type answers). I did in the end get an answer that was something I would not have thought of on my own and I am looking forward to trying it.

I feel like as the questioner, I need to be very specific about what answers I have thought of but are not satisfactory to me. I need to make sure the common sense answers are out of scope because I have already listed them as unsatisfactory to me in the question.

Comment: This is true. Also, some hack answers have been somewhat contrived, even less useful than a common sense method.

Answer (score 2):

Not always.  I have gotten some answers that are a variant of "There is no answer to your question."  Such answers do not add anything and are--so far--wrong, even though they get upvoted.  For example, see [How can I improvise sunglasses?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/1600/100)

If there truly is no answer to a question, then the lack of answers will indicate that there is no answer.  Yet.

Comment: Just a note: One of the statistics that shows whether or not a beta is healthy is the answer rate. If we have lots of unanswered questions it won't look good for us.

Comment: Also, one way to get better answers is to show more effort and thought in your question itself. It seems that you have some questions that have been downvoted and closed; perhaps you could go through and improve your questions a bit?

Comment: @ZachSaucier Don't look at the stats too intently, the SE team will decide whether or not this site is good enough. Not the stats.